# How to make files created by a specific user to have specific permissions by default

Tags: permissions, users, group

Here's a sequence of commands and the resulting output:

```
$ touch testfile
$ stat -c'%a %A' testfile
644 -rw-r--r--
```

What must I do so that when a user follows that sequence, I get this output instead:

```
664 -rw-rw-r--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX [defines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/umask.html) the utility `umask` which sets the file mode creation mask, either for the current instance (without subshells), or for every newly invoked shell (over .bash_profile, .bashrc, etc.).

Show the currently set mask in octal or symbolic form:

```
$ umask
0022
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
```

The octal numbers indicate the values which are getting removed from the full access:

```
$ umask 0002     # or: umask g+w
$ touch testfile
$ stat -c'%a %A' testfile
664 -rw-rw-r--
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) for that user to 0002.  Right now, it's probably 0022.  You can define it in your ~/.bash_profile with 'umask 0002'.

Answer (score 0):

Under bash, umask sets the file-creation mask. With umask 002 you get the permissions you want. You can put this in .bash_profile locally or globally.